# Python3 JSON parse with duplicate keys

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing, duplicates, key-value

Sorry for the newbie question, there is a json response like this;

```
import json

jsonObj = json.loads("""
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name_space": "name",
      "value": "Angelina"
    },
    {
      "name_space": "surname",
      "value": "Jolie"
    },
    {
      "name_space": "year",
      "value": "1975"
    }
  ]
}
""")
```

and I am currently able to parsing this way

```
for meta in jsonObj['data']:
    if meta['name_space'] == 'name':
        print(meta['value'])
    if meta['name_space'] == 'surname':
        print(meta['value'])
    if meta['name_space'] == 'year':
        print(meta['value'])
```

I'm researching if there are different ways to do this and make the code look cleaner or simpler.

Comment: Do the data dictionaries always have a "name_space" entry or "value" entry? Does the "name_space" tell you what other values are available in the dict?

Comment: What are you trying to print? `for meta in jsonObj['data']: print(meta['value'])` would print the same thing you print in your example. If you want something different, then include that in your question.

Comment: Nearly ~30 "name_space" or "value" data dictionaries and a few similar ones, for example I want to use `year` value to get `1975`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clean_dict = {x['name_space']: x['value'] for x in jsonObj['data']}` would give you the following `dict`:

`{'name': 'Angelina', 'surname': 'Jolie', 'year': '1975'}`

That code uses the `x['name_space']` value as your new keys in the `dict`.

Then you should be able to print it however you'd like, such as `print(clean_dict.values())`.

Comment: is it possible to get the `'value'` of value using `'name_space'` value?

Comment: `clean_dict['name']` would give you `"Angelina"` if that's what you mean.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)